# Separador de milhares

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework, razor

Como poderia colocar separador de milhares em um `textBoxFor()`?

Exemplo:

Valor inserido na `View` 1.321 ( O ponto é só para facilitar visualmente)e o 
controller receberia o valor 1321 para inserir na base.

Meu campo e `Int`e uso o `ValidationMessageFor()`. Quando coloco o ponto ele retorna o erro pelo fato de ter ponto.

Códigos:

View

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.contatoEfeitvo)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.contatoEfeitvo)
```

Controller

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
   indicadoresmassivosp.status = (TempData["status"] ?? "2").ToString();
   indicadoresmassivosp.dataAtualizacao = DateTime.Now;
   indicadoresmassivosp.idUsuario = usuario.UsuarioId;
   db.Entry(indicadoresmassivosp).State = EntityState.Modified;
   db.SaveChanges();
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Coloca o código pra gente ver como está. Especialmente que controle está usando. Este ponto é separação de milhar?

Comment: Posta o código aí.

Comment: bigown, o ponto só quero mostrar visualmente pois usuários está falando que ta ruim de visualizar sem o ponto , adicionei os códigos era isso que você precisava ?

Answer (score 2):

Se você puder mudar o controle pode usar isto na *view*:

```
Html.EditorFor(model => model.contatoEfeitvo)
```

Eu acho este controle até melhor.

Aí no *model* usa na propriedade do `contatoEfeitvo`:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{N0}")]
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/FormatNumber.cs).

As outras formas me parecem gambiarra.

Comment: bigow, Obrigado pela ajuda, porem não funcionou =\

Seguindo sua logica fiz dessa forma, 
@Html.TexboxFor(model => model.contatoEfeitvo , "{0:N0}") 
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N0}")]
Com isso ele traz o valor com ponto e na controller sem ponto ,tudo certo.
Mas quando eu vou dar update ele reclama do ponto.!

Comment: A pergunta não tem detalhes suficientes para dar uma solução completa. Eu fiz o que pude  com o que tinha.

Comment: Obrigado. Seu modo me deu a ideia, com campo decimal 18,0 ele funciona normal da sua forma ( já faço isso com monetário  {0:n} ) vou procurar porque o campo int não funciona.!

Comment: @EdgarAraujo a resposta responde a sua pergunta?